# Updating a CSV parsing script

Tags: sql, vba, csv

I'm trying to modify a parsing script to exclude a record in the first field that does not have a value but I want the script to finish the file.

```
lastRO = ""
FirstLine = True
FacilityCode = Left(InputFile, InStr(InputFile,"_")-1)

Do Until EOF
    a = CSVParser(ExtractLine(0))

If a(1) <> lastRO Then
    If FirstLine Then
        FirstLine = False
    Else
        WriteFields()

    End If
    lastRO = a(1)
    Field("Department") = ""
    Field("RepairOrder") = FacilityCode & a(1)
End If
Dim xReg
Set xReg = new  RegExp
For i = 0 to Ubound(RepairOrderDepartmentExpressions)
    xReg.Pattern = RepairOrderDepartmentExpressions(i)
    If xReg.Test(a(RepairOrderDepartmentField(i))) Then
        If Field("Department") = "" Or Field("Department") = RepairOrderDepartmentKey(i) Then
            Field("Department") = RepairOrderDepartmentKey(i)
        Else
            Field("Department") = RepairOrderSharedDepartment
        End if
        Exit For
    End if
Next
Skip
Loop
```

Comment: can you be more specific as to what is happening? are you getting an error? When you step through the code (and you HAVE stepped through the code, right?) what path is executing that you don't expect. If the files are too big for you to test with, create a sample file with 2 or 3 lines with the conditions you are checking for and ensure it works with the small file, and step through your code line by line.

Comment: Is `a()` a 1-based 1-dimensional array?